# JAVA Не более одной точки в jtextField

Tags: java, swing

Есть textField в который пользователь вносит значение. как сделать так, чтобы он не мог прописать больше, чем одну точку? Пытаюсь сделать подобным образом,но как-то не работает, что не так делаю?

```
    public static Document filter() {
        dot = 0;
        PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attr)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                // fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr); // remove non-digits
                fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""), attr); // remove non-digits

            }

            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attr)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""), attr); // remove non-digits
                System.out.println("REPLACE");

                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("FOR");
                    if (str.charAt(i) == '.' && dot == 0) {

                        dot++;
                        System.out.println("IF 1" + dot);
                    } else if (str.charAt(i) == '.' && dot == 1) {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
                        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                        fb.replace(off, len, sb.toString(), attr);

                        System.out.println("str " + fb);

                    }
                }

            }
        });
        return doc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Исходя из статьи (ссылка ниже) современный вариант №1.[Документация к DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html)***

```
    public class MyTextFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private char thatDelete; // что будем удалять
    private int counts;      // максимум возможных "повторений" символа
    
    public MyTextFilter(char thatDelete, int counts) {
        this.thatDelete = thatDelete;
        this.counts = counts;
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {
        if (containsNumbersMoreInClass(str)) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        } else
            super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);

    }

    private boolean containsNumbersMoreInClass(String z) {
        if (z.charAt(0) == thatDelete) {
            if (counts <= 0) {
                System.out.println("bye!");
                return true;
            }
            counts--;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

***Чтобы прикрутить к jtextfield***

```
JTextField jf = new JTextField();
    jf.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    ((AbstractDocument) jf.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MyTextFilter('.',1));
```

***Вариант 2.***

изначально пытался унаследоваться от JtextField но так и не понял, какой метод оверрайдить на приём входящего символа, мне показалось что это в принципе невозможно.Немного погуглив, мне помог этот вопрос [Ссылка на англоязычный стак](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458047/remove-last-character-from-jtextfield)

Получилось вот что.
Повторюсь, считается как @Deprecated

```
    JTextField jf = new JTextField();
    jf.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

    AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
    char point = '.';
    jf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            String word = jf.getText();
            if (e.getKeyChar() == point) {
                if (ai.get() == 0) {
                    ai.set(1);
                    jf.setText(word);
                }
                else 
                // + предусмотреть вариант, где пользователь может
                // вставить символ в другую часть строки
                jf.setText(word.substring(0,word.length()-1));
                
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: То что нужно спасибо. воспользовался первым вариантом. однако, если пользователь поставил точку и стер ее, то второй раз поставить точку он уже не сможет