# JTextField ввод только цифр

Tags: java, jtextfield

Создан калькулятор.

```c
public class CalcForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form CalcForm
     */
    public CalcForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        xText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        yText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        totalText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        subButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        mulButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        divButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        clearButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("X:");

        jLabel2.setText("Y:");

        jLabel3.setText("=");

        xText.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                xTextActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        xText.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                xTextKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        addButton.setText("+");
        addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        subButton.setText("-");
        subButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                subButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        mulButton.setText("*");
        mulButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                mulButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        divButton.setText("/");
        divButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                divButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        clearButton.setText("Очистити");
        clearButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                clearButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(totalText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(clearButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(yText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(xText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(mulButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(addButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 55, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(subButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 55, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(divButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(76, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(addButton)
                        .addComponent(subButton))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                        .addComponent(xText)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(yText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(mulButton)
                    .addComponent(divButton))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(totalText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(clearButton))
                .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    
    private void clearButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         xText.setText(" ");
            yText.setText(" ");
            totalText.setText(" ");                              
    }                                           

    private void mulButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String s = xText.getText();
            String d = yText.getText();
                Float x = Float.parseFloat(s);
                Float y = Float.parseFloat(d);
                    totalText.setText(String.valueOf(x*y));
    }                                         

    private void divButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         String s = xText.getText();
            String d = yText.getText();
                Float x = Float.parseFloat(s);
                Float y = Float.parseFloat(d);
                    totalText.setText(String.valueOf(x/y));
    }                                         

    private void subButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         String s = xText.getText();
            String d = yText.getText();
                Float x = Float.parseFloat(s);
                Float y = Float.parseFloat(d);
                    totalText.setText(String.valueOf(x-y));
    }                                         

    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String s = xText.getText();
            String d = yText.getText();
                Float x = Float.parseFloat(s);
                Float y = Float.parseFloat(d);
                    totalText.setText(String.valueOf(x+y));
    }                                         

    private void xTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void xTextKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                


                     
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CalcForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton clearButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton divButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JButton mulButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton subButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField totalText;
    private javax.swing.JTextField xText;
    private javax.swing.JTextField yText;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: простите, а в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Почти дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1377655/java-Не-более-одной-точки-в-jtextfield/1377687#1377687

Answer (score 0):

#### Main:

```
JTextField num = new JTextField();
PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) num.getDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new DigitFilter());
```

#### DigitFilter.java:

```
public class DigitFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    private static final String DIGITS = "\\d+";

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }
        
    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, string, attrs);
        }
    }
}
```